# Como atualizar a versão do php no xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

Estou estudando php e baixei diretamente pelo site do php (php.net), a versão windows e estou rodando no localhost pelo prompt de comando. Porém, queria utilizar o xampp como servidor local, mas quando uso o comando `php -v` no prompt de comando com o xampp instalado, o mesmo aponta para uma versão antiga (5.6), e gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de atualizar para a versão do php no xampp que baixei diretamente do site oficial.

Comment: Essa resposta no SOen pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792439/2570426

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigado!

Comment: Creio não ser possível sem desinstalar a versão anterior.
porém você pode fazer backup do banco e dos projetos, desinstalar e instalar a nova versão.
no final importe o banco e cole os projetos.
segue o link de um tutor:
https://medium.com/@asif.rocks/how-to-upgrade-xampp-in-windows-the-easy-way-93031fc923ce OBS: não esquecer de copiar a htdocs.

Comment: Segue tutorial completo neste [link](https://webhostingmedia.net/update-xampp-php-version-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso o Wamp mas o Xamp tem o mesmo comportamento e tenho um vhost para cada sistema que uso no meu diretório do C:\DEV. No caso eu não mexo e é interessante você você deixar seu XAMP com a configuração padrão e caso deseje alterar você muda no vhost que criar.

Assim você deve:

1) Baixar a versão que deseja do PHP e cole dentro da pasta do seu XAMP que contém o PHP:

(não tem problema ter as outras versões, no vhost você muda para a versão de PHP que quer usar)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) Altere conforme seu antigo arquivo o que você precisa no php.ini  (extensões, diretório, etc)

3) Crie o vhost para seu site e insira a configuração do php que você deseja. Exemplo:

(a configuração abaixo parte do pressuposto que você tem os arquivos do seu sitema no diretório 'C:/DEV/seusistema', adapte a sua pasta)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:/DEV/seusistema/public"
    ServerName seusistema

    <Directory "C:/DEV/seusistema/public">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Files ~ "\.php$>"
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FcgidWrapper "c:/WAMP/PHP-7.2.12-NTS-WIN64-VC15/php-cgi.exe" .php
    </Files>


</VirtualHost>
```